# LARAVEL : How to autofill form using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-9, autofill

I'm making a form for leave allocation, the form data consists of 2 table relations to table_karyawan and settingalokasi. when I select the kategori_cuti, tanggal_masuk form will appear where this form will be filled when the user selects nama_karyawan.

so the nama_karyawan and tanggal_masuk data come from the same table. I've tried to fetch the data using jquery ajax, but haven't been able to until now:
this is my controller for getTglmasuk:

```
 public function getTglmasuk(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $getTglmasuk = Karyawan::select('tgl_masuk')
        ->where('id', $request->id_karyawan)->first();

        if(!$getTglmasuk) {
            throw new \Exception('Data not found');
        }
        return response()->json($getTglmasuk);
    } catch (\Exception $e){
        return response()->json([
            'message' =>$e->getMessage()
        ], 500);
    }
}
```

and this is the route:

```
Route::post('/gettglmasuk', [AlokasicutiController::class, 'getTglmasuk'])->name('get.Tglmasuk');
```

this is the form in blade.php:

```
 <form class="input" action="{{route('alokasi.store')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                @method('POST')
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group col-sm">
                            <label for="id_karyawan" class="col-form-label">Karyawan</label>
                            <select name="id_karyawan" id="id_karyawan" class="form-control">
                                <option value="">Pilih Karyawan</option>
                                @foreach ($karyawan as $data)
                                    <option value="{{ $data->id }}">{{ $data->nama }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="form-group col-sm" id="jeniscuti">
                            <label for="id_jeniscuti" class="col-form-label">Kategori Cuti</label>
                            <select name="id_jeniscuti" id="id_jeniscuti" class="form-control"> 
                                <option value="">Pilih Kategori Cuti</option>
                                    @foreach ($jeniscuti as $jenis)
                                        <option value="{{ $jenis->id }}">{{ $jenis->jenis_cuti }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="durasi" class="col-form-label">Durasi (Hari)</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="durasi" placeholder="durasi" id="durasi">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="mode_alokasi" class="col-form-label">Mode Alokasi</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mode_alokasi" placeholder="mode alokasi" id="mode_alokasi">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6" id="validitas">
                        <div class=""  id="tanggalmulai">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="tgl_masuk" class="form-label">Tanggal Masuk</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" id="tgl_masuk" name="tgl_masuk" autocomplete="off" readonly>
                                    <span class="input-group-addon bg-custom b-0"><i class="mdi mdi-calendar text-white"></i></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="" id="tanggalselesai">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="tgl_selesai" class="form-label">Tanggal Sekarang</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" id="tgl_sekarang" name="tgl_sekarang" autocomplete="off" readonly>
                                    <span class="input-group-addon bg-custom b-0"><i class="mdi mdi-calendar text-white"></i></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class=""  id="start">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="tgl_mulai" class="form-label">Aktif Dari</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" id="datepicker-autoclosea1" name="tgl_mulai" autocomplete="off">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon bg-custom b-0"><i class="mdi mdi-calendar text-white"></i></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="" id="end">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="tgl_selesai" class="form-label">Sampai</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" id="datepicker-autoclosea2" name="tgl_selesai" autocomplete="off">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon bg-custom b-0"><i class="mdi mdi-calendar text-white"></i></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="save">Save Changes</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

and this is the javascript:

```
<script>
$("id_karyawan").on('change',function(e){
    var id_karyawan = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: '{{route('get.Tglmasuk')}}',
        data: {'id_karyawan':id_karyawan},
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(data){
            var json = data,
            obj = JSON.parse(json);
            $('#tgl_masuk').val(obj.tgl_masuk);
        }
        // error: function(response) {
        //     alert(response.responseJSON.message);
        // }
    });
});
```

Comment: can you console.log(data) in success function ?

Comment: in your ajax you send id_karyawan, why in your controller get $request->tgl_masuk ? try change $request->tgl_masuk to $request->id_karyawan, and change where column to id_karyawan

Comment: I have edited the code for the controller

Comment: and add console log in success function, and look response in console

Comment: in controller or javascript sir?

Comment: in js ajax success function, like this success:function(data){
            console.log(data)
        }

Comment: Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/alokasicuti
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Comment: this error ajax or submit Save Changes button ?

Comment: save changes button,when I select employee_name there is no message in the console

Comment: if no message in the console, check in tab network, and find gettglmasuk, tab network like this https://wd.imgix.net/image/BrQidfK9jaQyIHwdw91aVpkPiib2/Q4AZ84qTJLEnfToJYVLR.png

Comment: in the network, error like: gettglmasuk | status 419 |  type xhr |

Comment: click this network and click tab Preview or Response

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lc6BWpKS_sjAtZcBmFgGQzQdTiTYGgt7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: click gettglmasuk, and click tab Preview or Response

Comment: {message: "CSRF token mismatch.", exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException",…}
exception
: 
"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\HttpException"
file
: 
"C:\\laragon\\www\\hrms\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler.php"
line
: 
385
message
: 
"CSRF token mismatch."
trace
: 
[{,…},…]
0
: 
{,…}
1
: 
{file: "C:\laragon\www\hrms\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php", line: 51,…}

Comment: if you use ajax in laravel, send csrf in your ajax like this data: {"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}","id_karyawan":id_karyawan},